# Java: how to make a scrollbar scrolls with constant velocity?

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, jscrollbar

i want to make a java GUI program. it contains a jScrollpane which contains a big jPanel. the jPanel it's self contains lots of Swing components like jButtons, jPanels and... .what i want is when the user clicks on a jButton the jScrollpane starts to scroll to the end of big panel with a constant velocity. something like android OS.
as I know I must know how to make animation with java to solve this problem, I tried to solve that simply with Threads but it is not possible and it seems that swing needs more specific use of threads...
could you please give me your ideas? is it related to Swingworker ?
really really critical...:(

Update: I tried to solve that with timer class:

```
       ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (mainContainerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue() == mainContainerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getMaximum())
                timer.stop();
            mainContainerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(mainContainerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue() + 5);
            mainContainerScrollPane.repaint();
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer(10, action);
    timer.start();
```

the problem now is the animation is not smoothly done. i mean it scrolls smoothly on but as it reaches to a specific place it's speed comes down. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, any event that changes a GUI component should be run on the event dispatch thread (EDT). You can use a swing `Timer` to fire repeated events on the EDT as explained in this tutoria. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html. On the timer event, you can increment the scrollbar's value to whatever the new position should be. Repeat this with the same increment to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: there is only one problem, what i said in update...where the problem comes from?

Comment: Maybe it can't keep up with a timer at 10 Ms. try slowing the timer down a little bit. also be sure to check for greater than or equal to max value in case the max value is not an increment of 5

Comment: yeah, the problem was solved as I changed 10 to 100. but this is NOT what I want as it doesn't make as much fast animation as I want. I can not increase the value added to the value of the scrollbar each time,too. as that doesn't make a smooth animation. I'm not familiar with SwingWworker...may that solve the problem? if not, so please give me your great ideas friend :) thanx

Comment: Try different values in between 10 and 100. also instead of calling getHorizontalScrollbar and getMaxValue each time in actionPerformed, get those values once outside the loop. SwingWorker will not help here. It is for doing long running background tasks.

Comment: it got better now !  thanx. but why, why the timer limits us to select delay time ?

Comment: The timer doesn't limit it. It's just that it couldn't run the loop fast enough to keep up with a 10ms

Comment: so, it depends on CPU, RAM and...? and maybe this timer with e.g. 20 ms works on my machine and doesn't work on end-user's machine ?

Comment: That's part of it. Garbage collection could cause some hiccups as well. If you're really interested in what's taking up the milliseconds, run a profiler on the code.